# NodeJs, AngularJs, Mongoose giving error: TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object at Function.keys (native)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Heres my code relative to the problem:
server.js file:

```
app.post('/user', function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
    var user = mongoose.Schema('User',req.body);
    user.save(function(err,user){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        console.log("Successfully added user to MongoDB");
    });
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Angular Controller:

```
app.controller('RegisterController',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.submitData = function(user){
        var dob = user.dob.day.toString()+"/"+user.dob.month.toString()+"/"+user.dob.year.toString();
        user.dob = dob;
        var post = $http.post('/user', user);
        post.success(function(data,status,headers,config){
                console.log(data);
                console.log(status);
                console.log('Success!');
            });  
    }
    $scope.countTo= function(count){
        var array = [];
        for(i = 1; i<=count; i++){
            array.push(i);
        }
        return array;
    }
    $scope.countFrom = function(startingPoint,count){
        var numbers = [];
        for(i=startingPoint; i>startingPoint-count;i--){
            numbers.push(i);
        }
        return numbers;
    }
}
```

Mongoose Schema:

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: { 
        type:String,
        required: true
    },
    dob: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    postcode: {
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    address: {
        type:String,
        required:true
    }
});

var User = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
```

This is the error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)
    at P:\learning\Blink\server.js:35:41
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (P:\learning\Blink\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (P:\learning\Blink\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (P:\learning\Blink\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (P:\learning\Blink\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at P:\learning\Blink\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
    at Function.process_params (P:\learning\Blink\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
    at next (P:\learning\Blink\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
    at serveStatic (P:\learning\Blink\node_modules\express\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:74:16)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (P:\learning\Blink\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (P:\learning\Blink\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
    at P:\learning\Blink\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (P:\learning\Blink\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
    at next (P:\learning\Blink\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
    at P:\learning\Blink\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:129:5
```

The error occurs when I click the send button on the website... Any help please?

Comment: *"The error occurs when I click the send button on the website."* no it doesn't... it occurs when line 35 of server.js is executed. What line is that?

Comment: Your usage of mongoose.schema seems a bit... weird. usually you define the schema somewhere else during server initialization, not during an http request.

Comment: Line 35 is:  var user = mongoose.Schema('User',req.body);

Comment: Whats the waht you would initialize a mongoose schema? coudl you give me a small example?

Comment: Any other help you could give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are doing the Mongoose side of things a little wrong here. Not 100% sure this is the cause of your error, but it's still problematic.

`var user = mongoose.Schema('User',req.body);`

This isn't doing what you think it does. Schema expects an object representing the Schema as the first argument e.g., {email:String, dob:String}. Passing the string 'User' here would not work.

Instead, you want to reference the model you've already defined. You can do so by either

- exporting and subsequently including your user model as a module like `var User = require('UserModel.js')`
- or directly referencing the model from Mongoose (assuming it's defined in the app before you call it) like `var User = mongoose.model('User);`

Once you have a reference to the Model object you can initialize a new document. In your case you probably want your code to read something like

`var user = new User(req.body);
user.save(function(err,user){...}`

Try that and then let us know if you are still seeing that error.